# EmberJS multiple controllers on one page

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to have multiple controllers on one route / page. I want to show 2 features of my application on one page. But they are not directly related so each would need it's own controller, model and (partial) view.

But I can't seem to figure out how I could do this.

It seems that I must use the `{{render}}` option here.

Is it possible to have a subdirectory structure here?

When I have `{{render "dashboard.users"}}` for the template it does look in template/dashboard/users.hbs but for the controller I can't seem to find where it looks and what the naming conventions should be.

E.g. should it be

```
App.DashboardUsersController = ... ?
```

edit:

Looks like it should be, but I shouldn't place it in a subfolder of controllers but name it  `dashboard_users_controller.js`

Answer (score 0):

You get this effect by rendering templates into multiple outlets of their parent template: [Guide](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/rendering-a-template/) and  [API Docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate)

Here is a running [JSBin demonstrating it](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/qazedude/1/edit?html,js,output)